# How to write a regex statement for Minecraft chat?

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm currently writing a JavaScript application using the [Mineflayer API](https://github.com/andrewrk/mineflayer).  The Mineflayer API allows the creation of Minecraft bots using a powerful, stable, and high level JavaScript API.  I'm trying to write a regex statement to pull three different stats from a certain chat message.  The message displays as, "$1 has been received from [Legend] Steven_."  I want to write a regex statement to recognize that message and grab the amount of money, the user's rank, and the payer's name.  I have included an working example version of what I would like to do using Minecraft's private messaging ststem.

```
bot.chatAddPattern(/^\[ (?:\[[^\]]*\] )?([^ :]*) -> me ?] (.*)$/, "whisper", "WoodyCraft.net");

bot.on('whisper', function(username, message, type, rawMessage, matches) {
  bot.chat("/tell " + username + "It worked!");
  console.log(username + ": " + message);
});
```

Source: https://github.com/andrewrk/mineflayer/blob/master/examples/chatAddPattern.js

I would also appropriate an link to how the example was written because I couldn't find any that covered this specific method.

Comment: Try [`/^\$(\d+).*\[([^[\]]*)\]\s+(\w+)\.$/`](https://regex101.com/r/xZ1dY7/1).

Comment: @stribizhev That didn't work but "^\$(\d+(?:\.?(?:\d+))?).*?\[([^[]+)\].*?(\S+)\.$" worked besides the username returns as null.

Comment: Try appending `type, rawMessage, matches` arguments to the `function`. I see there are 2 capturing groups in the `whisper` regex pattern, and perhaps, those are for `username` and `message`, and those 3 must be some default args... perhaps.

Comment: That unfortunately didn't work.